# Python to connect to Oracle with OVD

Tags: python, oracle

I need to check oracle connectivity using python script.
My oracle connection string is in below format.

jdbc:oracle:thin:@ldap://ovd.mycomp.com:38901/cn=Oraclecontext,o=eus,dc=mycomp,dc=com/pidev ldap://ovd- mwdc.mycomp.com:38901/cn=Oraclecontext,o=eus,dc=mycomp,dc=com/pidev.

I tried https://dbajonblog.wordpress.com/2019/12/18/python-and-cx_oracle-for-oracle-database-connections/ but that did not help.
Could you please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: And the error you are getting is ..... what?

Answer (score 1):

The general cx_Oracle documentation on working with [JDBC and Oracle SQL Developer Connection Strings](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/connection_handling.html#jdbc-and-oracle-sql-developer-connection-strings) has some info however if you're using LDAP you'll need to do some extra configuration.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/32151099/4799035 and https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/issues/1212#issuecomment-591940440  The steps are the same for cx_Oracle.  Also see [Connect to DB using LDAP with python cx_Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64426038/connect-to-db-using-ldap-with-python-cx-oracle)

Answer (score 0):

I created following script using cx_oracle, which works fine.
only restriction is the dns name should be TNS entry.

**Script:**

```
import cx_Oracle
import sys
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
connection = None
def isOracleHealthy(dbname, username, password, dns, log):
    try:
        sys.stderr.write(dns)
        connection=cx_Oracle.connect("{}/{}@{}".format(username, password, dns))
        cur=connection.cursor()
        for result in cur.execute("SELECT * FROM dual"):
            log.info(result)
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        sys.stderr.write(dbname+' Oracle health check failed.\n')
        log.error(dbname+' Oracle health check failed.')    
        return False
```